# extjs beforestaterestore in gridfilters

Tags: extjs

In extjs,  gridFilters, we have:

```
grid.on({
scope: this,
beforestaterestore: this.applyState,
```

I am unable to understand what exactly is the beforestaterestore doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `beforestaterestore` event is fired before a Grid is loaded, assuming that the `stateful` config option was used when creating the Grid.

The code that you've listed will call the Grid's `applyState` method when this event fires, which will copy properties from the state provider to the Grid object.

I would strongly advise taking a look at the [ExtJS Documentation for the Grid Panel](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.GridPanel) for more information.

Comment: +1 for link to the API - it should be everyone's first port of call for ExtJs problems.